# Rails 4 Strong parameters for associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I do have My users model in Rails4 application and I have Defined

```
def user_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:email)
end
```

but I am also storing users address in a separate address table and I am filling up email and address both from a single form so how do I add address parameters as well in users strong parameters permit method.

Comment: Can you update your question with the form code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so:

```
def user_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:email,  address: [:address_attribute])
end
```

Take a look at [THIS](http://patshaughnessy.net/2014/6/16/a-rule-of-thumb-for-strong-parameters) post, I think it is pretty good at explaining strong parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Strong parameters should look like this:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, addresses_attributes: [:field1, :field2,..])
end
```

And also make sure that

user.rb

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
```